# How to restore network access after accidental removal of network packages

Tags: debian, networking

I recently tried to upgrade my Debian system, and ended up removing some crucial networking packages. I no longer have a working network connection.

I lost the Debian packages:

```
cockpit-networkmanager cockpit-storaged crda dnsmasq-base eject exfat-fuse exfat-utils iputils-arping iw
libatasmart4 libbluetooth3 libdbus-glib-1-2 libgudev-1.0-0 libjansson4 libjim0.76 libmbim-glib4 libmbim-proxy
libmm-glib0 libndp0 libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnm0 libpcsclite1 libqmi-glib5 libqmi-proxy libsoup2.4-1
libteamdctl0 libudisks2-0 modemmanager network-manager python3-dbus udisks2 usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data
wireless-regdb wpasupplicant
```

A log of the commands I ran and it's output can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/vamega/c7d15581cc0bea4919daca389a39cf60). That link contains the three commands I ran, and their respective outputs.

I think my system in running on `networking.service`, which means I should add some files to `/etc/network/interfaces.d`? Is there a way to auto-generate these files the way the Debian installer would have done?

EDIT: Answering some questions from the comments below.

This is a server system, I don't have a 3G connection here, and no wireless card attached. I just want to connect the `eno3` interface to the LAN, and have it configured via DHCP.

`/etc/resolv.conf` has a line `nameserver 192.168.1.1` line in it. I think I manually put that there, but it is also what I would expect if DHCP was working correctly.

Comment: Debian used to (I've switched to Devuan) keep a copy of every installed package under /var/cache/apt/archives or something like that.

Comment: Yes, but what packages should I be reinstalling?

Comment: You have the list in your auto-remove log

Comment: What is the output of iwconfig? What desktop are you running, gnome? If running gnome, what happens when you try to sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome

Comment: @MichaelProkopec perhaps you should read the question?

Comment: Configure the ethernet interface/an ip address by hand temporarily (or maybe wireless) to be able to download packages, you have lost network manager to make it automatic, and apparently lost a small part of the wireless subsystem, but it might still work. If you had a 3G interface - you are are not telling us, you definitively lost it temporarily. - I am not making wild guesses about the interfaces, just looking at the lost packages -  I advise trying to understand and read the output of commands before using them in the future, not following blindly recipes over the net.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro what would cause Debian to consider the network packages no longer necessary?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille  We do not have the full logs of the OP of what he did before the autoremove to answer that clearly. Maybe mixing versions/repositories or trying to install/deinstall a specific package. apt shows what it will be doing before asking for ok *for a reason*. You should not trust blindly all the decisions.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Ah, they are not the full networking packages at the end of the day. They are the network manager packages, I actually do not use them - except for wpa_supplicant. However, the OP has to tell us wether he lost a 3G interface, and whether at home or enterprise and if he has a network router, or otherwise the question is  pending on the too broad side.

Comment: Edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` file with  `nameserver 8.8.8.8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` , add your network interface:

```
auto eno3
iface eno3 inet dhcp
```

Then run:

```
ifup eno3
```

Move the files under `/etc/network/interfaces.d` to your home directory (the directory should be empty to avoid any conflict with `/etc/network/interfaces`). Next step , edit your [sources.list](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList) and disable third party repository. Reinstall the removed packages.

[5.4. The legacy network connection and configuration](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_legacy_network_connection_and_configuration)

Comment: Or just to get things working `dhclient -v eno3`

Comment: @ivanivan `ifup` will found this stanza `iface eno3 inet dhcp`  in the `interfaces` file  to call the dhclient.

Comment: This brought back my internet.
I've reinstalled the missing packages, and things look great now.

I think this came about as a result of me trying to use `cockpit` which required me to enable the `stretch-backports` repository.

Normally I'd not use `network-manager` for a server, but it seems like `cockpit` has it as a dependency.